# PHP HTTP Request with more than one Variables?

Tags: php, url, httprequest

I want to send 3 Variables per HTTP Request to another site and want get the Response.

check.php:

```
<html><body> 
 
  <form action="response.php" method="post">
   <p>Variable1: <input type="text" name="var1" /></p>
   <p>Vairable2: <input type="text" name="var2" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" /></p>
  </form>
</body></html>
```

response.php:

```
<?php 

 $url = "http://www.testpage/api.php?authcode=";

 $apikey = "xxxxxxx" ;

 $request = new HTTPRequest($url$apikey&$var1&$var2, HTTP_METH_POST); //req not work !
 $request->send();                                                    //nothing happens
 response = $request->getResponseBody();                              //only
                                                                      //got
 echo "$response ";                                                   //500 error

?>
```

Comment: You need to concatenate the variables...

Comment: `$url . $apikey . '&' . $var1 . '&' . $var2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = "http://www.testpage.com/api.php";
$r = new HTTPRequest($url, HTTP_METH_POST);
$r->addPostFields(array('authcode' => $apikey, 'var1' => '', 'var2' => ''));
$r->send();
```

Replace empty fields in array with your values for var1 and var2.

Also, you may want to use cURL rather than built-in HTTP handler. 
[PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Comment: Hi thanks for your anwsers and hints, but i got still the 500 error.
Iam now trying the curl sample.